# How to enable and configure WiFi in debian 7 wheezy.?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, configuration

I just installed the debian 7 wheezy, but WiFi is not working.
I visited the debian wiki pages but they have already mentioned there that the broadcom chip BCM43142, 4e4:4365 is not supported by the drivers packages 43xx etc

what to do please help.?

it works fine when I installed Windows.

but not on debian distribution .

Answer (score 1):

This might be in interest of yours.

At first get the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms broadcom-sta-modules
```

1st package isn't essencial.

[download this package](https://mega.co.nz/#!qIUySZYJ!PgfNRVCcXO-enbDuhziUqVCriMcDhbU-houaQ97c0yM)

Install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb
```

And run:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: I have not tried your solution but got tired of trying to just enable my laptop WiFi, even I tried Ubuntu, Fedora, Kali and debian.
and with all of them I had the same problem.

so I just uninstalled it for now, will try that . thanks